# Moved some files and they're no longer found

Tags: lts, mv

I had some times in `/var/WWW/html`, I wanted to move them into a directory in same folder but since I couldn't move folder into itself so decided to move all files from `/html` to `/var/WWW, so I did:

```
mv * ..
```

But now I cant find all those files in "WWW" directory, I even tried `ls -a` but nothing.

I've tried searching and locating the files but no results, is there a way to get those files back?

Comment: maybe some of them still are in old path: `ls -la /var/WWW/html`

Comment: Are you sure it was /var/WWW/ and not /var/www/?  See if `history` shows you what `cd` command you did before the `mv`.

Comment: it was /www not WWW  114  cd /var/www/
  115  ls
  116  cd html
  117  ls
  118  mkdir ogp
  119  mv * ..

Comment: Please post the result of `ls -a /var/www` and `ls -a /var/www/html`

Answer (score 1):

Check the `/var` directory, and if you know one of the file names you can also try

```
>$ locate filename
```

If command `locate` is not installed install it as follows:

```
>$ sudo apt update
>$ sudo install mlocate
```

The database is update once daily by using a cron script but you can update it manually using

```
>$ sudo updatedb
```

Comment: The `locate` command uses a database that is usually only updated once per day

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for them with the command:

```
find / -iname *.html
```

this will search your computer for all html files, replace the html with whatever file extension you used(.css, .php, etc.).